# Why JS object console log gives NaN instead of Number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

From .NET backend we receive by GET method to Google Chrome an object

```
Delivery {
 Id: 1, 
 ShippingDateTime: null, 
 ApproximateHandoverDateTime: null, 
 Charge: 527, 
 Cost: null
}
```

If we look at the preview of GET method `Delivery.Charge` is `527`.

BUT if we type `console.log(Delivery)` it will give that `Delivery.Charge` is `NaN` !!!

Moreover if we type `console.log(Delivery.Charge)` it will give `527` !

What is going on? Please, explain!

**UPDATE**
If even after GET method I type Delivery.Charge = 123 anyway console.log(Delivery) gives me Delivery.Charge as NaN. Crazy!

Comment: try changing the name of the object

Comment: it is just an example. the real name is Delivery. @johnny5

Comment: Okay,  how are you using console log didn't you say this was in .NET

Comment: @johnny5, I said that we receive it. We receive it in FrontEnd by Get method. All next actions we make in browser.

Comment: what happens if you console.log(Delivery)?

Comment: what do you get with ``console.info( typeof Delivery )``

Comment: yeah your might be receiving the object as text

Comment: @johnny5, I will get what I wrote in code tags.

Comment: @Stevanicus, it will log "Object"

Comment: can you post you GET ajax method?

Comment: Guys, it is angular syntax.
I make $http.get(url)

Comment: Can you post the code that is running it then

Comment: Show us where you get / assign `Charge`

Comment: Also try doing `console.log(Delivery)` after running this line: `Delivery.Charge = parseInt(Delivery.Charge, 10);`

Comment: @Diego, it will help, but its ridiculuous!!)  It is not a decision)

Comment: It is just a test to run, not to leave your code like that. I truly believe that the issue is where you create / assign the `Delivery.Charge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property name to anything but "Charge".

For instance, Charge -> DeliveryCharge:

```
Delivery {
 Id: 1, 
 ShippingDateTime: null, 
 ApproximateHandoverDateTime: null, 
 DeliveryCharge: 527, 
 Cost: null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of the object should be:

```
var Delivery = { 
    key:value,
    key:value
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Delivery is an object and you can not print it out directly.
You have to write a method that the same toString() in Java.
See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HoangTran/275afbg4/) for example.

```
var Delivery  = {
Id: 1, 
ShippingDateTime: null, 
ApproximateHandoverDateTime: null, 
Charge: 527, 
Cost: null
```

}

```
function test(){
    alert(JSON.stringify(Delivery)) //you use stringify to get all elements of oject.

}
```